# Can I have two different styles of bibliography in the same document?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, subdividing

It is possible in the same document, change the style of bibliography?
 I want the bibliography by chapters arranged in order of appearance. (I use `unsrt`), but I want the general bibliography in alphabetical order (and, if possible, `backref` to pages where the citation appears).

Comment: You should mention how you arrange the bibliographies by chapter. I'd recommend switching to **biblatex** that is able to do this and more.

Answer (score 6):

that's not really possible. What you can do is to create one bibliography, rename the file
`<file>.bbl` to `<file>-bib.tex` and then run your document with the setting for the other bibliography. The first created can simply be inserted into your main TeX document by `\input{<file>-bib}`