# Using different bibliographic styles in the same document

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, subdividing, bibunits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have two different styles of bibliography in the same document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22202/can-i-have-two-different-styles-of-bibliography-in-the-same-document)

I'd like to use in the same document:

1. the numerical style in `natbib` to list my own bibliography using `bibunit` (to separate Journal papers from conference papers, and so on ...),
2. and then the `authoryear` style in `natbib` to list the bibliography of the whole document at the end of that document.

It is however mentioned in the `bibunit.pdf` file, which comes with the `bibunit` package, that: "With `natbib`, you cannot use numerical and author-year reference schemes together. ..." And that is exactly what I'm experiencing because my end bibliography appears in the numerical style which is not desired.

I've noticed that if I comment the numerical style bibliography (as described in the number 1 above), I get my end bibliography displayed in the author year style as desired.

How to manage to get `natbib` display in the same document numerical and author-year styles?

The `natbib` package is loaded with the `authoryear` option

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for answering Thorsten,
Prior to posting the message I've tried the solution proposed in the post you mention (renaming the file etc.), but it did not work in my case.

Comment: @rasha Since the proposed solution in the question that Thorsten linked to is a manual solution, what exactly didn't work?

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn.
The latter bibliography appears in the numerical form, even after copying manually the file, renaming, etc.
The only solution which is somehow working is the one described in:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17058/switching-between-numeric-and-authoryear-in-natbib

It consists of defining the new command
\newcommand\Mycite[1]{%
  \citeauthor{#1}~[\citeyear{#1}]}

However this solution is not completely satisfactory as it does not allow to take profit of many features of natbib as for example multiple citations is the same cite command \cite{ref1,ref2,ref3}.